# phoneGap Android - Populate database once "Error processing SQL:1"

Tags: android, database, cordova, populate

I am trying to avoid populate the database if the database exists but when I try to cancel this line in my code I get **"Error processing SQL:1"**

```
tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
```

this is my whole populate function

```
 function populateDB(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, word TEXT NOT NULL');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, word) VALUES ("1", "Apple")');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, word) VALUES ("2", "Orange")');

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function has set of issues which are corrected below. It should work now.

```
    function populateDB(tx) {
        isTableExists(tx, "DEMO", function(status) {
            if (!status) {
                alert("table not exist, creating one");
                tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE DEMO (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, kword TEXT NOT NULL, eword TEXT NOT NULL, pronoun TEXT NOT NULL, level INTEGER NOT NULL)');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (kword, eword, pronoun, level) VALUES ("Apple", "", "", 1)');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (kword, eword, pronoun, level) VALUES ("Orange", "", "", 2 )');
            } else {
                alert("table exist, dropping for test");
                tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE DEMO');
            }
        });
    }

    function isTableExists(tx, tableName, callback) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DEMO', [], function(tx, resultSet) {
            if (resultSet.rows.length <= 0) {
                callback(false);
            } else {
                callback(true);
            }
        }, function(err) {
            callback(false);
        });
    }
```

Comment: hi, I edited the question (some mistake when I write question for the SQL) when I left out the "id" from "INSERT INTO DEMO (id, word)" I get Error processing SQL:5. I am trying not to execute insert SQL if table DEMO exist.

Comment: sorry but i dont understand your question now, do you want to create table everytime you run the application??

Comment: I only want to create table one time and all those entry execute again every time I load the pages again.

Comment: so you want to create tables only once, and put data also only once??

Comment: Yup. I just want to set up all the table entries once which is at the beginning of applications install only.

Answer (score 6):

Why dont you use

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO  (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, kword TEXT NOT NULL, eword TEXT NOT NULL, pronoun TEXT NOT NULL, level INTEGER NOT NULL)
```