# Do I have to drop the table before creating it in Sqlite?

Tags: javascript, sql, sqlite, cordova

When I initialize my Sqlite Database I make it as follows:

```
 var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 20000);
 db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
 function populateDB(tx) {
tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TimeTable');
tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TimeTable (id  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY      AUTOINCREMENT, Day, Subject, StartingTime, EndingTime)');}
```

Now, I don't want the table to be dropped every time I call this function. 
But when I remove this line:

```
tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TimeTable');
```

An error shows:

```
[INFO] Error processing SQL: 1
```

Is there a solution for this ?

Comment: I think you first need to delete table in database level.. and then run updated script, where you have commented `drop table` statement.

Comment: Where do I write the database level file ?

Comment: I was telling that first you have to delete this table from database, as it is already present in the database .. that's why I was thinking you should first clear the table from database.. But as you have `create table "if not exists"` then this thing is not required..
you can ignore last comment.

Comment: try this solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/using-already-created-database-with-android/9109728#9109728

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try the solution posted there:

[phoneGap Android - Populate database once "Error processing SQL:1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942971/phonegap-android-populate-database-once-error-processing-sql1)